# Load only rows into Dataframe Based on searching for sub-string in the row from unstructured format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have unstructured datasets that use a legacy Java program which are currently loaded based on a specific string within the row that is comma delimited. For example if the row contains "PAT" in one of the columns, then every row that has that string is loaded into a column within a SQL database. This happens for several different strings.

What makes this unique is every different type of string has a different number of "columns" or different amount of delimited fields to them. I'm rewriting this program in Python and trying to perform ETA on the dataset for verification.

Essentially, what I want to do right now is search through the file for a specific string and load all rows that contain that string into a dataframe in pandas. Due to the different number of columns in the rows, I can't load the file into a dataframe and then filter from there. Is it possible to pre-search for a string before loading into a dataframe?

Date Example:

```
123456,20010101,14:03:55.425,FAN,*,*,*
123456,20010101,14:03:55.425,PAT,0.00,0.00,0.00
123456,20010101,14:03:55.425,CON,*,*,*
123456,20010101,14:03:55.425,TRUNK,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
123456,20010101,14:03:55.462,FAN,*,*,*
123456,20010101,14:03:55.462,PAT,0.00,0.00,0.00
123456,20010101,14:03:55.462,CON,*,*,*
```

Comment: _Is it possible to pre-search for a string before loading into a dataframe._ Yes, it likely is. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

The "in" keyword is great for testing if something is in a data set. Here's an example using the built-in CSV module.

```py
import pandas
import csv

with open("data.csv") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    keyword = "PAT"
    keyword_dataframes = pandas.DataFrame([row for row in reader if keyword in row])

    print(keyword_dataframes)
```

Output

```
        0         1             2    3     4     5     6
0  123456  20010101  14:03:55.425  PAT  0.00  0.00  0.00
1  123456  20010101  14:03:55.462  PAT  0.00  0.00  0.00
```